# Select only where all rows for a "customer" have the same status?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a status table with a bit field `closed`

I want to try and select all `CustomerNumber`s where ALL of the rows for that customer are `closed`

The following works...but I'm sure there is a more sensible way of doing it!

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT
          lcs.CustomerNumber AS CustomerNumber
        , COUNT(lcs.CustomerNumber) AS Total
    FROM Status lcs
    GROUP BY lcs.CustomerNumber) total
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        lcs.CustomerNumber AS CustomerNumber
        , COUNT(lcs.CustomerNumber) AS Closed
    FROM Status lcs
    WHERE lcs.Closed = 1
    GROUP BY lcs.CustomerNumber) closed
ON closed.CustomerNumber = total.CustomerNumber
WHERE closed.Closed = total.Total
```

Each customer can have one or more rows, each either closed=0 or closed=1

I need to select only when ALL of the rows for the customer are closed.

Sample:

```
CustomeNumber     Closed
111               0
111               0
112               1
112               0
113               1
113               1
114               1
```

This should select:
113 and 114
Both have ALL of their status's as Closed.

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: added some examples to explain a little clearer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  customerNumber
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY customerNumber
HAVING  COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN closed = 1 THEN 1 END)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da89d/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════════════╗
║ CUSTOMERNUMBER ║
╠════════════════╣
║            113 ║
║            114 ║
╚════════════════╝
```

Comment: @AmitSingh of course it will only output `114`. what output do you expect? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c09f/1

Comment: @AmitSingh: No, this is correct...113 now does NOT have all "Closed" status, so should NOT be selected.

Comment: i think op wants that if the last recod is 1 than it should be displayed...thats what i think

Answer (score 3):

Another way of solving it would be:

```
SELECT CustomerNumber FROM Status WHERE closed = 1
EXCEPT
SELECT CustomerNumber FROM Status WHERE closed = 0
```

The values returned from [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) will be distinct so no need to add that.